# Flutter Colors I want to get a string value for the color

Tags: flutter, colors

Am a little new to flutter and Dart and hope you can help. I'd like to get a string/text value of the current color being shown on the screen, so Colors.blue would be give a string 'blue'. Can anyone help with this please?
Thanks so much

Comment: Do you mean you want to get hex code in String?

Comment: can you be more specific ? based on where user touch and what colour user touch or you have value like Colors.blue and you just want to trim the string ?

Comment: I'd like to get a text string e.g. "blue" to identify when Colors.blue is being used. I guess a hex string would be ok, as long as I have a consistent idenifier, so that I know when Colors.blue, Colors.green, Colors.red etc are being used. They can change in my app, based on user input.